# Как получить доступ к стилям из JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сейчас у меня есть стиль в `style.css`:

```
transition: all .25s ease;
```

И на jQuery у меня есть код:

```
$('.card.ticket').css('transition-duration')
```

Который возвращает строку, например, `0.25s`. Как сделать то же на JavaScript? Следующий код возвращает пустую строку:

```
document.querySelector('.card.ticket').style.transitionDuration
```

Comment: Последней вашей строчкой всё же можно получить стиль, при условии, что он уже прописан в HTML, в атрибут `style="..."` (вручную или через JS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `getComputedStyle`. Эта функция позволяет получить реальные значения CSS свойств https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.card.ticket');
const style = getComputedStyle(element);

console.log(style.transitionDuration);
```

```css
.card.ticket {
  transition: all .252s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="card ticket">card ticket</div>
```